# Php email issue with localhost

Tags: php

I am trying to send email in my local using `PHP mail` function but email are not send. Also it shows a warning message as below.

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" 
  port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini
```

Comment: you have to setup smtp in php.ini

Comment: @DhruvPatel : No, you can set it via `ini_set()`

Comment: @Shivan Raptor I said in php.ini

Comment: @DhruvPatel , not really have to . it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cant send mail from your localhost, if you haven't configured SMTP. So for configuration you can do it as following:

If you open the php.ini file, you will find these two lines:

```
smtp_server
smtp_port
```

Add the server and port number for your host (you may need to contact them for details)

So you will need to add them to be able to send mail from a server that requires authentication. So an example may be:

```
smtp_server = mail.example.com or any IP address(where SMTP is configured)
smtp_port = 25
```

And if required, then add the following two lines don't exist:

```
auth_username = username
auth_password = pw
```

Think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explained. The `mail()` function cannot connect to your mail server. Check your mail server settings.

Try to telnet to port 25 to see whether you can connect to mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have a SMTP server running on your machine, see if you can telnet to port 25 on your local machine to see if it is running or not. Or perhaps your mailserver is configured to listen on another port and PHP is configured to try the default port of 25.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server doesn't have a smtp mailserver running. You could use these functions to set a different smtp server:

```
ini_set('SMTP', "server.com");
ini_set('smtp_port', "25");
ini_set('sendmail_from', "email@domain.com");
```

You're probably not running an SMTP server on your localhost.

if you only need an SMTP server for development purposes, and you're running Windows, install smtp4dev, which can be found here: http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

Use [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) Instead. It has good support for all mailing problems.

Here you can find dozens of [Examples](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/ExamplesPage)

Comment: I don't know why I got -1 on this.

Comment: I guess the -1 guy thinks that you answer is not related to the issue, as the problem is, OP is unable to connect to mail server. Using another mail library does not help.

Comment: Forum is becoming fun. I thought the error is telling the user what is wrong. I just tried to just make it simpler so that developer doesn't have to go to configuration level.

Comment: Agree with you. Focus on development is more meaningful. Another popular mail library is SwiftMailer.